# Why does team-bot equipment disappear?

Tags: lotr-war-in-the-north

In Lord of the Rings: War in the North, there are three main characters. The game has co-op functionality. If you're not playing with others, the other two characters are played by AI. The game supports drop-in, drop-out co-operation.

One bug is that all of the gear that a team-bot had equipped, which comes to them by virtue of you gifting it to them, may not be restored once a player who replaced that bot, leaves.

Why does this happen? Is it avoidable without eschewing multiplayer altogether?